# How to add the data from different class in one XML file?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a three classes i want to add the all classes data in one XML file?

fist class is:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FirstName + " " +LastName + " "  +Email;
    }
}
```

second class is :

```
public class Student:Person
{

    public Student()
    {
    }
    public double AssessmentGrade { get; set; }
    public double AssignmentGrade { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + "," +AssessmentGrade + "," + AssignmentGrade;
    }
}
```

Third Class is:

```
public class Teacher:Person
{
    public string RoomNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + "," + RoomNumber;
    }
}
```

I made a DB Class too where i store all the data in XML file.

```
    private const string path = @"Persons.xml";

    Public static void SavePersons(List<Person> Persons)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.IndentChars = ("   ");

        XmlWriter xmlOut = XmlWriter.Create(path, settings);
        xmlOut.WriteStartDocument();
        xmlOut.WriteStartElement("Persons");

        foreach (Person person in Persons)
        {
            Student student = new Student();
            Teacher teacher = new Teacher();

            xmlOut.WriteStartElement("Person");
            xmlOut.WriteAttributeString("Email", person.Email);
            xmlOut.WriteElementString("Firstname", person.FirstName);
            xmlOut.WriteElementString("Lastname", person.LastName);
            xmlOut.WriteElementString("AssessmentGrade",
                                      student.AssessmentGrade.ToString());
            xmlOut.WriteElementString("AssignmentGrade", 
                                      student.AssignmentGrade.ToString());
            xmlOut.WriteElementString("Room", teacher.RoomNumber.ToString());

            xmlOut.WriteEndElement();

        }
        xmlOut.WriteEndElement();
        xmlOut.Close();
    }
```

Now problem is this how to add Student Class and Teacher class in the Same XML.I tried to add but it doesn't work.Can you please help me.

Comment: I created two object and add the information in it but it doesn't work

Comment: Why don't you use XmlSerializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is store `Person`, `Student` and `Teacher` separately, but in the same file, and using the same logic? Maybe something like this:

```
foreach (Person person in Persons)
{
    // Edit: After reading the comment below, I 
    // updated the methods to return an XmlWriter. This
    // way, you should be able to contiune working with the 
    // same instance:
    if(typeOf(Student).IsInstanceOfType(person)){
        xmlOut = AppendStudentInfo(person, xmlOut);
    }else if(typeOf(Teacher).IsInstanceOfType(person){
        xmlOut = AppendTeacherInfo(person, xmlOut);
    }else{
        xmlOut = AppendPersonInfo(person, xmlOut);
    }
}

xmlOut.WriteEndElement();
xmlOut.Close();

(...)
```

Then create three helper-methods to write the data. This is an example for Students:

```
// (Edit: Updated to return an XmlWriter)
private XmlWriter AppendStudentInfo(Person person, XmlWriter xmlOut){

    Student student = (Student) person;
    // For teacher, use this instead:
    // Teacher teacher = (Teacher) person;

    xmlOut.WriteStartElement("Student");
    xmlOut.WriteAttributeString("Email", student.Email);
    xmlOut.WriteElementString("Firstname", student.FirstName);
    xmlOut.WriteElementString("Lastname", student.LastName);
    xmlOut.WriteElementString("AssessmentGrade",
                              student.AssessmentGrade.ToString());
    xmlOut.WriteElementString("AssignmentGrade", 
                              student.AssignmentGrade.ToString());
    xmlOut.WriteEndElement();

    // (Edit: Updated to return an XmlWriter)
    return xmlOut;
}
```

Now for `Teacher`, you would do the same, but using that type instead of `Student`, and including fields relevant to the teacher-type (ie `Room` instead of `AssignmentGrade` and `AssessmentGrade`).

For Person, you would do the same, but only include the fields that exist in the class `Person`.

I haven't tested this code, but believe it should be more or less correct. Hope this was something like the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Hi can you please tell me How to save the whole data in this it override the data and save only last one but i want to save the whole data.

Comment: Glad to help! I'm not 100% sure how this works, but returning the updated instance of XmlWriter (the variable `xmlOut`) might fix your problem. See the updates in my code.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your code it should be erroring out on these three lines. :

```
xmlOut.WriteElementString("AssessmentGrade", student.AssessmentGrade.ToString());
xmlOut.WriteElementString("AssignmentGrade", student.AssignmentGrade.ToString());
xmlOut.WriteElementString("Room", teacher.RoomNumber.ToString());
```

This is because you declare your new student and teacher objects above but you do not provide a value for AssessmentGrade/AssignmentGrade/RoomNumber.

Am I understanding what your issue is?

```
student.AssessmentGrade = 90;
```

Comment: You just set a value to these.  Updated answer but you will have to also probably set a value to your list of people.  You may already be doing that but that is what you are passing into your function.

Answer (score 0):

Use DataContractSerializer to serialize data in xml format:

```
Public static void SavePersons(Persons persons)
{
  var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Persons));
  // Create a FileStream to write with.
  FileStream fs = new FileStream("file.xml", FileMode.Create);
  using (fs)
  {
     ser.WriteObject(fs, p);
  }
}
```

Class Persons:

```
[KnownType(typeof(Student))] 
[KnownType(typeof(Teacher))]
[DataContract]
public class Persons
{
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<Person>{get;set;}
}
```

Another example on it:[MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx#Mtps_DropDownFilterText)